# Перебор хэша внутри объекта с использованием Object. Ошибка свойства

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Никак не могу разобраться с Object и хэшем в Javascirpt.

Есть объект с конструктором такого вида:

```
const FirstObject = function () {
  // somedata
}
```

У него есть метод, который для примера просто выводит в лог текст.

```
FirstObject.prototype.text = function () {
  console.log('some text');
}
```

Второй объект с конструктором такого вида (создание хэша и заполнение его экземплярами FirstObject):

```
const SecondObject = function () {
  this.somedata = {};

  this.somedata[0] = new FirstObject();
  this.somedata[1] = new FirstObject();

  // ...
}
```

У него есть метод перебора хэша и запуска метода объекта FirstObject.

```
SecondObject.prototype.sendtext = function () {

  Object.keys(this.somedata).map(function (key, index) {
    this.somedata[key].text();
  });

}
```

Однако, при запуске sendtext, получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'somedata' of undefined
```

Не понимаю, почему оно считает свойством this 'somedata'.
При замене this.somedata на somedata работает:

```
let somedata = this.somedata
Object.keys(somedata).map( ... )
```

Однако такой подход глаза режет. Как можно лучше поступить в данном случае?

Comment: Почитайте про контекст (`this`) в js. Это типичная ситуация.

Comment: для перебора, а не создания нового массива лучше использовать `forEach`. `this` можно передать вторым аргументом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [стрелочную функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) у которой нет своего контекста:

```js
const FirstObject = function () {
  // somedata
}

FirstObject.prototype.text = function () {
  console.log('some text');
}

const SecondObject = function () {
  this.somedata = [];

  this.somedata[0] = new FirstObject();
  this.somedata[1] = new FirstObject();
}

SecondObject.prototype.sendtext = function () {
  Object.keys(this.somedata).map((key, index) => this.somedata[key].text());
}

const x = new SecondObject();

console.log(x.sendtext());
```

P.S. Также, я заменил `this.somedata = {}` -> `this.somedata = []`;